# Why does this window object not have the eval function?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, yui, eval, mshtml

I ran into an interesting (?) problem in the [YUI rich edit demo](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/skinning_editor.html) on IE. When looking at the `window` object for the content editable frame used as the browser I see that the `eval` function is undefined (by running the following).

```
javascript:alert(document.getElementById("editor_editor").contentWindow.eval)
```

This only happens on IE (I checked on IE6 and IE8), and it doesn't happen on Firefox or Chrome.

All the other [`window`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) functions and properties seem to be in order, now I realise that `eval` is *not really* defined on the `window` but on the global object but my understanding was that in browsers the `window` **is** the global object (also `eval` does appear on all other windows so why not on this one?).

Does anyone know if this is a know bug/limitation in IE and how I can get to `eval` in the context of the global object of this frame? (I need the side effects to be available to anything running from within this frame).

Comment: Not to intentionally toot the *eval is eval* horn here, but maybe there's another way to achieve what you're trying to do without using `eval`?

Comment: No-one's going to argue with you that *eval is eval*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered a while back that you can make `eval` magically appear in an iframe's window object in IE by using `execScript` first:

```
function evalIframe(iframeWin, command) {
    if (!iframeWin.eval && iframeWin.execScript) {
        iframeWin.execScript("null");
    }
    if (iframeWin.eval) {
        iframeWin.eval(command);
    } else {
        alert("No eval!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I tried it and got "Access is denied": `javascript:try { document.getElementById("editor_editor").contentWindow.execScript('null')  } catch (ex) { alert(ex.message) }`

Comment: Oh. This has worked for me on iframes I've created dynamically. I'd expect `eval` not to work either then. All I can think of is that it could be because YUI editor is using a `data:` URL as the `src` for the iframe, which may be causing IE to prevent access because the iframe URL is using a different protocol to the main document's URL.

Comment: When I look at the `src` I see `javascript:false` in IE (`data:...` for Firefox but not for IE), I'll keep digging.

Comment: If you come up with anything, please post again: I'd like to know the answer to this too.

Comment: no progress on this (other things took priority) however I did discover that (in IE8) this doesn't happen if the debugger is attached...